# Opening VPN connection broke VNC

Tags: vpn, vnc

I connected to my machine using VNC and then opened a VPN connection to my work network (from that machine). Now the VNC is unresponsive -- it seems to be in a "read-only" mode. I can view the screen and even copy files over VNC, but I can't click anything.

Is there a way to fix this remotely?

Answer (score 0):

Connect from any WorkNetwork IP, disable "Use default gateway" on VPN-connection (you **have it** now, and outgoing packets routed to another interface, than accept incoming)